# Subdivision sharpening random edges

Tags: mesh, edges, subdivision-surface

Transitioning from Maya to Blender, I'm working on a mesh in Blender 2.8 and when I apply a subdivision modifier all goes well except for one section, which seems to have frustratingly weird, sharpened edges. All vertexes and edges are merged properly, and the mesh is all in quads, what is going on here and how can I get it to smooth properly like everything else?
I attempted "merge by distance" just in case but this doesn't affect it at all.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!
[image: note the edge loop by the elbow]

Comment: Check if your normals are correct...

Comment: This looks like double vertices issue. In opposition to Maya you actually need to select all vertices in order for "merge by distance"to work. Alternatively you could try "Clear Custom Split Normals" operator.

Comment: Recalculated normals and it was fixed. Thank you!